# Storyboard TabBarController (without class files) in Landscape?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode-storyboard

I'm building a more or less complex app, but I'm quite new to this. I've created my own `ABCViewController`, which works fine with the `MainWindow.xib` (also in landscape mode), but now I want to create a `UITabBarController` (without code) which should be shown up before the `ABCViewController`. I simply tried using the storyboard, but when I run the app, the `UITabBarController` is in Portrait. The attributes inspector in storyboard is set to landscape for all my view controllers. Is it possible to edit the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method for the `UITabBarViewController`, which exists only in storyboard? I've also set everything to landscape in the `Info.plist`!

EDIT: Solved. I created the Vvew controllers which are shown in the tab bar controller, and then I used the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method and returned `YES` (not `(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)`) in every view controller.